# Google Scripts: How to get the name/email of the active editor?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I work on a Google Drive with other people and we have multiple google sheets.
I defined a "OnEdit" function to get the name of the people editing a specific column in a sheet,
so that I can send to discord the following message "User X has updated the sheet Y."

But I can't get the name of the current user (except me). I use the following script:

```
function getCurrentUserEmail() {
        var protection = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('A1').protect();
       
        protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
        var editors = protection.getEditors();
        if (editors.length === 2) {
            var owner = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getOwner();
            editors.splice(editors.indexOf(owner), 1);
        }
        var userEmail = editors[0];
        protection.remove();
return userEmail;}
```

I believe the user editing the script doesn't have the authority to execute "removeEditors"

The classic "Session.getActiveUser()" also doesn't work for anyone but me (it returns a blank)

It is starting to become frustrating; if it is a problem of access rights, what can I do?

Comment: If you don't have a workspace account (paid) it won't work - see my answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/65792464/10445017

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apps Script - onEdit combine timestamp and username/email address not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65784589/apps-script-onedit-combine-timestamp-and-username-email-address-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

Your users would need to authorise the script for it to work - this is so that you can't collect user data without their permission.

You could maybe try to run an `onOpen` check to see if the user has already authorised your script, and if not, prompt them to execute a placeholder function.

You could log authorisation from users (eg. on a hidden sheet).